# How do I loop through alll columns using Jinja in DBT?

Tags: sql, dbt

I want to iterate over all the columns using dbt.

Comment: Please expand with an example and some workable model / column name examples as well as the type of warehouse you are using (Snowflake, BQ, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the star macro from the dbt-utils package + some for-loop logic might help you here? This depends on the exact use case and warehouse you're using (as pointed out in the comments).

The [star macro](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils#star-source) generates a list of columns in the table provided.

So a possible approach would be something along the lines of:

```
{% for col in [{{ dbt_utils.star(ref('my_model')) }}] %}
...operation...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I stumbled on the dbt_utils.star but could not get it to ouput a list of columns. But I think adding the list brackets should do the trick

Comment: @NripeshPradhan great, did you manage to figure it out?

Comment: your suggestion worked for looping across all columns.

Comment: Thanks @NripeshPradhan, could you mark this as an accepted answer! Would be super useful!

Comment: there is a syntax error in the first line if I am not mistaken - it shall read `{% for col in [ dbt_utils.star(ref('my_model')) ] %}` without curly brackets around the macro

Answer (score 8):

You can use the built-in `adapter` wrapper and [adapter.get_columns_in_relation](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/adapter#get_columns_in_relation):

```
{% for col in adapter.get_columns_in_relation(ref('<<your model>>')) -%}
    ... {{ col.column }} ...
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the `model` node, and you have columns defined as [model properties](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/model-properties), this will work:

```
{% for col in model.columns.values() %}
  ... {{ col.name }}  ... {{ col.data_type }} ... 
{% endfor %}
```

You can get the model node from the [graph](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/graph):

```
{% set model = graph.nodes.values()
        | selectattr("resource_type", "equalto", "model")
        | selectattr("name", "equalto", model_name)
        | first %}
```